# How to create a character animation like Midjourney Official Website's

Tags: python, animation, character

I want to create an animation similar to https://www.midjourney.com/home/, wherein the title is generated gradually in the middle, and the animation on the periphery resembles spirals. Eventually, it transforms into rings upon rings.

I am planning to use Python to create this animation. Can you please provide me with some advice?

I am hoping someone could provide me with some code, or GitHub pages that I can refer to.

Comment: Python? You'd be better off with JavaScript[,](https://semicolon.dev/stackoverflow/question/14/how-to-make-consistent-characters-for-illustration-books-in-midjourney) if you want real-time rendering on the homepage. You can also use canvas tag for fast 2D drawing.